# Insert datetime as unix timestamp in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, sqlite

I have the following schema in ruby:

```
create_table "medidas", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "measurement_type_id"
end
```

So far, when inserting "medidas" the "date" attribute was inserting timestamps, but now it's inserting the dates in a different format, and I'm not sure why. It's relevant to note that there are other people involved in this project, so I might not be aware of other changes made. This is the code for the setter, in the class "Medida":

```
def timestamp=(timestamp)
    self.date = Medida.date(timestamp)
end

def self.date(timestamp)
    return DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s, "%s")
end
```

By doing this, what I get is dates in full length format, such as "2015-01-22 12:06:05". However, some older records show the dates as standard timestamps. Notice that I also tried that last line as `DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s, "%s").to_i`, in which case, the line `self.date = ...` fails, and `self.date` becomes `nil`.

This is odd, as previous database entries *still* list timestamps. Obviously, some queries rely on this fact and they fail for dates using the current date/time format. I would like to revert back to using timestamps, but I'm not sure how. Please advise.

Comment: the datetime column automatically returns a string. You're also altering the datetime with the "%s".

Comment: I'm OK with using strings, I'm just not OK with the format. How am I altering the datetime with %s?

Comment: Oh, you want to change the format of the datetimes in the DB?

Comment: Well, if that's what it takes, then yes. I want the database with timestamps.